# Should I give feedback to a company on their poor job description?

Tags: interviewing, communication, job-search

A company I’ve applied to had what I thought was a good job description. But when I got into the interview, the hiring manager mentions a key skill that isn’t listed in the description.

Therefore I get eliminated on an criteria that the hiring manager either forgot to write down or invented on the spot.

Should I point out to them, meaning the HR contact, that this criteria is missing from their job description?

Comment: Why didn't you bring this up during the interview?

Comment: Were you explicitly told that skill was the reason you were eliminated? Do you know if they were applying that criteria to other candidates or not (regardless of if it was in the JD)?

Comment: The hiring manager, or whoever I was interviewing with, said explicitly she was looking for people with "ABC" skill and asked for examples of that. Then she cut off the interview early.

Comment: @sf02 Because I wasn't looking at the job description during the interview, I was talking to the other person and answering questions they asked. Also, don't you think it seems a little confrontational for an interview? It sounds nice to ask anonymously online, but when talking to another person it could come across as extremely direct.

Comment: It's not confrontational if they said they are looking for people with ABC and you knew that ABC was not listed on the job description ( presumably, having read it prior to the interview ).

Comment: @sf02 Yes, but during the interview I'm focused on showing the skills I do have and how that fits their needs. Plus, who memorizes a job description? The chance is greater that it's something I misread vs something they included last minute. But when I'm not in the pressure of an interview, I can go back and read carefully again, and see that they only asked for new skills in the interview and not in the description.

Comment: I don't know about you but I have always reviewed the job description thoroughly prior to any interview as part of my preparation as well as bringing a physical copy to use as a reference.  Remember, you are also evaluating the company so the interview is the perfect time to bring up anything unclear or odd about the job description.

Comment: @sf02 I don't have a printer at home, so a hard copy is not impossible but not convenient. But I will keep your strategy in mind for next time. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm often feeling a need to do that. "No experience required - at least 5 years experience" "babysitter wanted - need to be able to wield" "high expertise level wanted - for a junior position".
The thing is - I would be wasting my time to let them know I THINK there is something wrong with their ad.
But was it? Maybe they know exactly what they're doing? Maybe the ad is not for hiring but just to be there? Maybe they want only naive gullible people? A specialist that will settle for junior pay?

At the end, I don't know. And I would only make them aware of that if I wasted time already (for example attending such interview). I would make them aware because that would be a thing I would other people know (for example by writing on glassdoor). That this company is hectic and unorganised that they can't even write proper ad. That it don't care about wasting people time. and/or have no clear goal and don't know what it want from it's employees.
In such case the feedback should be instant "You wasted my time".

Comment: Fair points. Maybe I'll just comment on Glassdoor.

Comment: I'm selecting this as the answer, because it's the only answer that points out that on the face of it, it's unknown why some companies write the job descriptions the way they do. Maybe they're lazy. Maybe it's required by law. Maybe they don't know what they want until after they start interviewing.

Answer (score 5):

It's unlikely to help.

Chances are they noticed this themselves: Interviewing costs time and money and if the lacking requirement eliminated the candidate through oversight, they are likely to update the JD and more importantly the pre-interview screening process.

If they are not smart or organized enough to take action on this, your notification is unlikely to make a difference.

If it was the requirement was made up on the spot to have a convenient reason to reject you, your notification won't do anything useful either

Answer (score 3):

What would you gain by telling them?  You won't get the role, but I guess it might keep your name in a slightly positive light should you apply for a different role.

If they haven't put in a key skill to their job description then they will no doubt not get the candidates they actually want, to me it would seem if they miss something basic like that then I'd be less eager to join that company.

Comment: Well I don’t know if it was missed or invented on the spot to eliminate candidates for non-merit reasons.

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean but you're missing the whole point of the answer. What would you gain? You have a slight chance of a loss and a zero chance of a gain (unless it's a HR position). I'm all for looking out for the company when in the job but while you are applying you need to look out for yourself.

Comment: *I guess it might keep your name in a slightly positive light should you apply for a different role* - or, it'll make you look like a nit picky complainer...

Comment: @KeithLoughnane The feedback would go to HR, although I'm sure he would pass that info to the hiring manager.

Comment: I'm not trying to badger you but again "What would you gain"?

Comment: @KeithLoughnane Ok thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @user70848 regardless of *why* it was not there, it is not your problem. It is very nice of you to think about saving time and effort from HR and Hiring Manager but the usefulness of it to the company is limited, it will not help you in any way and can even damage your image.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm downvoting this comment because the final conclusion is unrealistic on the basis that for the candidates they do select, this oversight will not be something that turns them away from the job.

Comment: @user70848 you can't downvote comments only flag them and I don't think this deserves to be flagged.